# Button matrix/multiple button + function for each one

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def create_widget(self):
    for x in range(11):
        for y in range(11):
            self.bttn = Button(self)
            self.bttn.grid(row=x, column=y)
            for c in range(len(path)):
                if [x,y] == path[c]:
                    self.bttn["text"] = numbers[c]
                    break
            else:
                self.bttn["text"] = randint(0, 200)

def select(self):
    print(self.bttn["text"])
```

Note:

1. `path` is the list of coordinates (example: `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1],
   [2, 1], [3, 1], [3, 2], [4, 2], [5, 2], [6, 2], [6, 3], [7, 3], [8,3], [8, 4], [9, 4], [9, 5], [10, 5], [10, 6], [10, 7], [10, 8], [10, 9], [10, 10]]`)
2. `numbers` is a randomly generated array of numbers (example: `[15, 21, 27, 33, 39, 45, 51, 57, 63, 69, 75, 81, 87, 93, 99, 105, 111, 117, 123, 129, 135]`)

I have a matrix of buttons and I want a function (e.g. `function select(self)`) to print the text of a clicked button. Right now it only prints text from the last clicked button.

Comment: You create 121 different buttons, and then repeatedly replace `self.bttn` with the newly created button.

Comment: The buttons must define some sort of callback interface so you know when you clicked one and also which one it was. I assume it might be the select method in which case you should subclass Button and override that method.

Answer (score 0):

Each new button you declare overwrite the same instance of `self.bttn` which leads to you in the end only having access to the lastly defined button. Thus, the buttons get created alright, but then you have access only to the last one. Thus, its name will be the one you access through `self.bttn` and therefore its name will be shown every time select is called.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to create a nested list to contain your buttons, and then find some way to retrieve the button that you want.

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
    self.buttons = []
    ...

def create_widget(self):
    for x in range(11):
        self.buttons.append([])
        for y in range(11):
            button = Button(self)
            self.buttons[-1].append(button)
            button.grid(row=x, column=y)
            for c in range(len(path)):
                if [x,y] == path[c]:
                    button["text"] = numbers[c]
                    break
            else:
                button["text"] = randint(0, 200)

def select(self, row, col):
    button = self.buttons[row][col]
    print(button["text"])
```

Depending on what information you are able to pass your `select` function, other structures might be better.